# static function declaration inside a block

Tags: c

A [tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03statdef.htm) said

> **You cannot declare functions within a block as static.**

What is the reason?How does it affect the function?

Comment: I thought you couldn't declare functions in a block, period. Unless I'm somehow missing the point.

Comment: @iWerner You can [declare functions inside a block](http://ideone.com/MD1Ja). You cannot *define* one function inside another though.

Comment: @iWerner A function _declaration_ is simply the function prototype. You can't _define_ nested functions (though some compilers add it as an extension).

Comment: @PavanManjunath Thanks. Time for more coffee, I suppose.

Comment: @SnehaSP Why on earth do you want to declare a function in a block static? If it is a static function, it should be somewhere in the same .c file as the block you're trying to declare it in, in which case you can move the function within the file, or add a prototype to the top of the file.

Comment: C99 Standard: 6.2.2: footnote 22: "A function declaration can contain the storage-class specifier static only if it is at file scope."

If it is only when it is file-scoped, then why would you put it inside a block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` when applied to functions means that the function has **internal linkage**. i.e. it can be accessed within this file only. In other words it has **file-scope**. This linkage applies irrespective of whether you declare a function inside another function or outside of all of them.

Now, if you apply the `static` keyword to a function *declaration* inside another block/function, **semantically speaking**, you are trying to restrict the scope of the function to that particular block/function, which goes against the language rules that state that `static` functions, irrespective of their place of declaration,  shall have file-scope.

And hence, the standard **might** be prohibiting such a declaration.

**PS**: Footnote `30` in `6.2.3` in the latest C11 standard states-

> A function declaration can contain the storage-class specifier **static**
>   only if it is at file scope;

Comment: Nice. Can anyone tell us where in the standard this is mentioned?